# NSTextField's selector triggered on lost focus?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I'm using an `NSTextField` as a search field, and it is bound to a selector. It is triggered when the return key is pressed *(as expected)*, but it is also triggered when the field loses focus.

I **don't** want the selector to be triggered on lost focus. Is it possible to get around this behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Interface Builder or the XIB editor of Xcode 4, change the text field's ***Action*** property to ***Send on Enter Only***.

[image: NSTextField action]

Answer (score 1):

See -sendsActionOnEndEditing in the NSCell documentation.